# Automated migration of artifact from snapshot to release repository in Nexus

Tags: nexus

I am exploring the possiblity of automated/scheduled migration of an artifact form a snapshot repository to a release repository.

Does Sonatype nexus provide such a feature ?

Thanks!

Comment: In my response I assume you are talking about maven since it's the only repository format with distinct repositories for type.  If you're talking about another format then that's good to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature in Nexus Repository Manager.
In essence (in Maven) it is another push as at minimum the version has changed.
This is the same sentiment for snapshot to snapshot only the repository is the same.